# How to change the time on a real device using Appium?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, time, appium

I want to automate the below manual step:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane,
                "Advance Device Time by 1 hour 30 minutes on the device and navigate back to the dashboard page in the App. Click 'OK' when done.");

I want to do this on a real device using appium

As of now, it is a manual step.

I know the code to get the device time:​ driver.getDeviceTime();

Now I need the code to change the device time.

Suppose the current time on the device is 9.00 AM. I want to change it to 10.00 am

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with JavaScript.

One solution I can think of is to introduce utility class.

Inside instance of said class you have lambda variable (equals 0 by default) and two functions.

First function gets real time from device and adds lambda to it.

Second function adds some variable to lambda.

In real life case you use only first function.

For test purposes you use second function.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share the code? Also how to set the device time with the new variable.